# EF Same where for different objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Look at the following senario:

```
 class CompanyDto  {
     public string Street { get; set;}
     public int Number { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr1 { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr2 { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr3 { get; set;}
     // Other not common Properties
 }

 class AnimalDto {
     public string Street { get; set;}
     public int Number { get; set;}
     // Other not common Properties
 }

 class HouseDto {
     public bool IsAttr1 { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr2 { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr3 { get; set;}
     // Other not common Properties
 }

 class PersonDto {
     public string Street { get; set;}
     public int Number { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr1 { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr2 { get; set;}
     public bool IsAttr3 { get; set;}
     // Other not common Properties
 }
```

I have these Dtos that I want to populate from Entinty Framework context. Thing is I want to filter the results using standard where clauses. 
Example:

```
 List<PersonDto> prs = context.Person.Where(x => x.Number == SomeValue && Street == SomeOtherValue).Where( x=> x.IsAttr1 || x.IsAttr2).Select(//projection here).ToList();

 List<AnimalDto> anmls = context.Animal.Where(x => x.Number == SomeValue && Street == SomeOtherValue).Select(//projection here).ToList();

 etc.
```

I want to project them to the Dtos (simple) but I don't want to write the Where clauses again and again. I tried to do this using extention Methods but failed misserably both while using base classes (Address and Flags) and while using Interfaces because IQuerable cannot be cast from Interface to Concrete class.

Is there any way I can do this?

The preferable way would be to have an extention method like this:

```
public static IQueryable<IAddress> WhereAddress(this IQueryable<IAddress> qry, int SomeValue, int SomeOtherValue)
    {
        return qry.Where(x => x.Number == SomeValue && Street == SomeOtherValue);
    }
```

But I cannot add the WhereFlags after the WhereAddress clause and the IQuerable.cast(); fails to do the cast.

Comment: Have you tried the repository pattern?
You could store these queries in the repository.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on this?

Comment: A repository is a layer between your EF and the frontend. this abstraction makes it usefull to store queries as methods in order to reuse them everywhere.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx
This is considered a good practice. Far better then extension methods if you ask me.

Comment: Hehe, I know what a repository is but I could not see how it would help me achieve what I want. I guess It could if I implemented the Where Clauses in a Repository<T> base class but unfortunately the design of the project is not up to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your extension method as follows with a constraint on the generic parameter to be of type `IAddress` and `class` (*this avoids the exception "LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types"*) and implement the interface on your types `Company`, `Animal` and `Person`

```
public static IQueryable<TAddress> WhereAddress<TAddress>(this IQueryable<TAddress> qry, int SomeValue, string SomeOtherValue)
  where TAddress : class, IAddress {
    return qry.Where(x => x.Number == SomeValue && x.Street == SomeOtherValue);
}
```

With this you can call

```
context.Person.WhereAddress(SomeValue,SomeOtherValue).Where(x=> x.IsAttr1 || x.IsAttr2);
```

but not

```
context.House.WhereAddress(SomeValue,SomeOtherValue);
```

cause `House` does not implement `IAddress`.

Comment: Same problem here,  LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras i fixed my answer. i hade to include the constraint `class` on the generic parameter also.

Comment: @Jehof does this compile though? I didn't think EF supported implicit casting i.e. `context.Person` wouldn't be `IQueryable<IAddress>` it would most likely be `DbSet<Person>`.

Comment: @James i have tried this in LinqPad and i get no compilation errors or exceptions during runtime and the execution returns the correct values.

Comment: I found the same solution. Thanks for the help I couldn't have found it if you had not pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetByAddress<T>(DbContext context, int number, string street)
{
    return context.Set<T>().Select<T, IAddress>(x => x.Number == SomeValue && x.Street == SomeOtherValue);  
}
```

Then externally you should be able to do

```
List<PersonDto> prs = GetByAddress<Person>(context, 1, "1234 Street")
                          .Select(...)
                          .ToList();
List<AnimalDto> anmls = GetByAddress<Animal>(context, 2, "5678 Road")
                          .Select(...)
                          .ToList();
```

If you prefer the extension method approach then you should be able to do that, the reason it doesn't work at the minute is because you aren't projecting the table to `IAddress`. LINQ doesn't support implicit casting e.g.

```
List<PersonDto> prs = context.Person.Select<Person, IAddress>()
                                    .WhereAddress(1, "1234 Street")
                                    .Select(...)
                                    .ToList();
List<PersonDto> prs = context.Animal.Select<Animal, IAddress>()
                                    .WhereAddress(2, "5678 Street")
                                    .Select(...)
                                    .ToList();
```